# Annotation get unselected when tap anywhere in MKMapView

Tags: ios, annotations, mkmapview

I don't want to get unselected an annotation whenever user tap on mapView. Although i don't want to use UIGestureRecognizer because it is upbringing too many problem in user interaction with map view. I want callouts to appear all the time until user select another annotation. I am using different annotation view for select and unselect state of annotation.

[image: I am using different annotation view for select and unselect state of annotation]

Comment: Why do you not want to unselect a map when you tap elsewhere? Do you want callouts to appear all the time? Perhaps you should have custom annotation that shows whatever bubble you want as part of the annotation view itself. I'd suggest you describe the broader business problem. Perhaps you can describe what you want it to look like.

Comment: Yes, I want callouts to appear all the time until user select another annotation. See my edited question with attachment, you will get broader idea about my problem.

Comment: They do continue to appear as you drag and pinch-zoom. The only time they disappear is when you explicitly tap somewhere else on the screen. As an aside, I'm a little confused by your screen snapshot because you have no callouts shown at all here. Or are you talking about that "frontier" view?

Comment: Yes, i am talking about "frontier" view with red color that one is selected and others are deselected. I want to stop call of deselected delegate method of map view when user tap anywhere in map.

Comment: But this doesn't appear to be a call out, but rather just something you added to the view hierarchy. So why worry about deselect at all? Just change your logic re how and where you add this call out and where you remove it. Bottom line, you can't easily prevent deselect, but I don't see why that prevents you from keeping that subview around. We probably need more info how this subview is being managed...